# How to see compiler errors when using Angular 2 with lite-server

Tags: angular, typescript, lite-server

I'm working in Angular 2 and if I have a compiler error when I do an npm start I see it right away.  The problem I'm running into is when I am doing live code edits and I introduce a an error.  I'm not seeing any compiler errors in the lite-server output so I have to stop and do another npm start to figure out what's wrong.

Is this just the way things are or is there a way to see errors when working this way?

[Update]

The scripts section of my package.json

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "tsc && concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" ",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "postinstall": "typings install",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "typings": "typings"
  },
```

Comment: Can't you see compile error(s) in `node.js command prompt`?

Comment: If not, Can you show me your `packag.json` file?

Comment: My command prompt gets replaced by the lite-server output.

Comment: `concurrently` is designed to concatenate all outputs and prefix them. Your package.json looks like it's from the Angular 2 Quickstart, which uses SystemJS and Angular2 in development mode. A lot of HTTP requests are made that way upon every live refresh (and, ofc, logged by lite-server). Maybe your terminal scrollback isn't large enough, so you don't see the compiler errors? Have you tried muting lite-server by doing something like `npm run lite > /dev/null`?

Comment: I've added it @micronyks  Thanks

Comment: Another thing you could try is to only show the output of the first parameter `npm run tsc:w` by doing `npm start | grep "\[0\]"` instead of `npm start`

Comment: Ahh thanks @talkdirty I see it now when I scroll back back.  Sadly I'm on Windows 7 without the new bash stuff so I can't /dev/null.  I'll look into how I can mute lite-server in other ways..